# InflateException While creating dialog box

Tags: android

I got an infalte exception during this code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
appContext=getActivity().getApplicationContext();
myContext=getActivity();
}

private void createAlertBox(final AppointmentRow appointmentRow)
{
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(myContext, R.style.Dialog);
View layout = LayoutInflater.from(appContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_autocomplete, null);
String[] from={"id","name"};
.....................
.....................
}
```

Exception occured in the following line.

```
View layout = LayoutInflater.from(appContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_autocomplete, null);
```

Exception is Android.View.InflateException.
Is there any solution?

```
    <com.example.netmdapp1.customViews.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/customautocomplete"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Patient name"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_modified_states"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <requestFocus />
</com.example.netmdapp1.customViews.CustomAutoCompleteTextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Xml part.Any Idea?

Comment: You don't need `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` getActivity() will give the activity context of the hosting activity

Comment: Could you please post your whole error message?

Comment: Pls reply.Error log is posted in the above section

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make following change :

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) your_Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_autocomplete, null);
```

Then use this 'view' with findViewById() instead of just findViewById() like

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code this line

```
View layout = LayoutInflater.from(appContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_autocomplete, null);

                     to

View layout = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_autocomplete, null);

                     or

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_autocomplete, null);
```

Comment: We need more code to find the root cause. Can you please post the custom_autocomplete xml file. Remove the confidential part or change the names